# How to scrape weather data using meteostat library in python for multiple locations?

Tags: python, web-scraping, weather, meteostat

I am new to web scraping and trying to get familiar with meteostat library. I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'postal code': [11, 12, 13],
    'latitude': [40.7128, 34.0522, 51.5074],
    'longitude': [-74.0060, -118.2437, -0.1278]
})
```

What I want to do is to retrieve daily min and max temperature for these locations starting for the period from 01.01.2022 to 31.12.2022. I am trying the code below:

```
# Set time period
start = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2022, 12, 31) 

# Create points for locations
df['point'] = df.apply(lambda x: Point(x['latitude'], x['longitude'], 70), 
                        axis=1)

# Get daily data for 2022
data = df.apply(lambda x: Daily(x['point'], start, end), 
                        axis=1)
data = data.fetch()
```

However, I receive the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'fetch'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the `Daily()` function to each row of the dataframe when you use `df.apply()`. This is creating a Series of `Daily` objects. Then you try to call `fetch()` on this series, but that doesn't work because you need to call it on a single `Daily` object (not a series of them).

You could try it like this:

```py
data = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    point = Point(row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
    
    daily_data = Daily(point, start, end)
    daily_data = daily_data.fetch()

    data.append(daily_data)

# Concatenate the data from all locations into a single dataframe
result = pd.concat(data)

print(result)
```

If you also want to return the postal code column you can add this line in your `for` loop before appending the data to the list:

```py
daily_data['postal code'] = row['postal code']
```

Comment: It is working fine, thank you. I also want to return postal code column in the 'result' data frame. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include this. If this solves your problem please accept the answer.